# GoogleDrive v3 API: revision representation does not contain enough info to download

Tags: google-drive-api

The revisions representation no longer provides a `revisions.downloadUrl` nor does it provide the `files.ID` of the file it is a revision of. In order to download a revision I need both the `files.ID` and the `revisions.ID`

Am I missing something, or is it weird that the revisions representation doesn't have enough information in it to download the revision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to be used for `downloadUrl` is `revisions.get` with `?alt=media`. Here's the [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields).

Also, per [Listing and downloading individual revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions#listing_and_downloading_individual_revisions),

> Once you get a list of a file's revisions, you can download the content of any revision by calling the [`revisions.get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get) method with the parameter `alt=media`. Revisions for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides can not be downloaded.

With this, try to get the list using [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list) which returns revision details in the response body with this sample structure:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#revisionList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "revisions": [
    {
       "kind": "drive#revision",
       "id": string,
       "mimeType": string,
       "modifiedTime": datetime,
       "lastModifyingUser": {
         "kind": "drive#user",
         "displayName": string,
         "emailAddress": string
       },
       "originalFilename": string,
       "size": long
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Teyam for the quick response.

I've read through the doc you posted and understand it. My consternation is caused by the fact that if I have stored the revision ID and that is the only info I have, I don't have enough info to download the revision in one call, or even two calls.

This is because `revisions.get` url is `v3/files/<fileID>/revisions/<revisionID>?alt=media` The revision representation doesn't contain the corresponding fileID.

Comment: Well anyway, I think I'm just complaining here. Your answer is the right one as near as I can tell.

Thanks again!